# Is there possibility in AS to show last commited changes like local one?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea

What I mean exactly is at the left (right) vertical panel like when
you edit a file. (with different color)

=>

[image]

It would be nice to have same function (with different color) but for last commit (or several). I know about **annotate** and about **local history**, but that is not what I want.

**Is there option like this? Or plugin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but there is a feature request for that:

- [IDEA-24398](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398) Pin editor diff highlighting to any earlier revision